# Appending matches into a new empty list by using a condition inside a for loop on an non-empty list in Python

Tags: python, regex, if-statement, for-loop, append

I have this list:

```
loss = ['strike', 'customer', '6', '.']
```

and an empty list:

```
profit = []
```

I want to tell Python that (1) ignoring non-alphanumeric items of the list, check every item of the list, (2) if a word starts with s (finding the letter s with a regex), append this word in a new list (profit), (3) else if a word start with c, append this word in a new list (profit).

How do I get

```
profit = ['strike', 'customer']
```

Comment: Why use a regex for something that simple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> for x in loss:
...     if x.startswith(('s','c')): profit.append(x)
... 
>>> profit
['strike', 'customer']
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use string methods instead of regular expressions:

```
>>> loss = ['strike', 'customer', '6', '.']
>>> profit = [x for x in loss if x.isalnum() and x.startswith(("c", "s"))]
>>> profit
['strike', 'customer']
```

(Actually, come to think of it, it might be better in the other order, `x.startswith(("c", "s")) and x.isalnum()` -- that way you skip the linear `isalnum` check if the easy `startswith` check fails.)

Comment: I was about to mention the edit you just posted. ;-) http://codepad.org/zhpUQ6Xh

Comment: @Vahidabdi: only in the sense that the OP explicitly mentioned it as a criterion.   It'll rule out things like `"put option"`, I guess.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: heh.  Sure, but you had to bump up the string length to 1k+.  Why not make it 1M+, so it's even slower?  ;^)

Comment: With small strings, the difference in efficiency is negligible.  However, as @AshwiniChaudhary demonstrated, there is a big difference with larger ones.  So, why not incorporate that idea into your code?  What's to lose?

Comment: @iCodez: ?  It's already there.  It was there before Ashwini mentioned it.  (If you mean why don't I edit the pre-existing code, I often like showing my work-- at least for me, code doesn't emerge in perfect form like Athena from the head of Zeus. :^)